# Is it possible to write a Skype client?

Tags: c#, .net, skype

Is there any libraries for this?

I will put this on a server and it will be a windows service.

And Skype **will not** be installed on server. So Skype API will not mean anything I guess.

Edit:

I am sorry for not being clear. Here is what i need:

I just need a Skype client which will act like a small bot. A person who uses Skype will ask it something like:

> print totalCreditsLoadedToday

And it will answer:

> 567867867 credits.

I need to write a windows service which will accept text messages from Skype and will send responses as text message (a very simple Skype client). I don't need voip support but Skype is a, errr customer requirement lets say. (And yes I suggested Google Talk but not accepted)

But i need to achieve this without installing Skype to the server.

Comment: It is, if you have a server who can host you application so people can connect to each other it's as simple/difficult as sending an audio stream from one place to another. Using it to call to real phone numbers however is a different story...

Comment: it's not clear from your question what you want to do.

Comment: If you can achieve your aims with any VoIP solution other than Skype, do that. Skype is very deliberately a closed protocol. Doesn't play well with others.

Comment: This sounds like an UI automation task:-D

Comment: Can some one give update for this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Skype communication is encrypted and no documentation is publicly available on the protocol. That means good luck reverse-engineering it.

Comment: Not only encrypted for privacy, but also deliberately obfuscated to make it difficult to reverse-engineer, specifically to frustrate any attempt to interoperate with the thing. Good luck indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to use Skype API without having Skype installed on the machine

Answer (score 1):

I think Skype has an API to use and there is some reverse engineering work done also, check this [link](http://skypejournal.com/blog/archives/2006/07/skype_protocols_opening_up_ready_or_not.php), and this [tutorial](http://www.jaanuskase.com/en/2006/07/the_adventures_of_writing_a_si.html)

Answer (score 0):

Skype needs to be installed for this to be possible and here's something long the line which could help you in building your requirement.

http://chathurangaw.blogspot.com/2011/08/skypepop-skype-notifications-enhanced.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the Microsoft Bot Framework. https://dev.botframework.com/

It supports Skype and a variety of other transports.